# JQuery UI Full Size Calender - Get JSON Data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI Full Size Calender ( Mostly Used for Event Management ).

I have a PHP file in which I have prepared a JSON.

**Take a look at that JSON File (json-events.php):**

```
echo json_encode(array(

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => "Event1",
        'start' => "2013-12-12",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 222,
        'title' => "Event2",
        'start' => "2013-12-16",
        'end' => "2013-12-19",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    )

));
```

**Now I want to use this data on my Event Calender. Here is the code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            events: "json-events.php",

            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }

        });

    });
```

Somehow it is not showing events. The whole Calender comes empty. No Console error.

Comment: did you parse the json you got from the php script using **JSON.parse(php json value);** ??

Answer (score 2):

You can get values from other page using following :

```
$.getJSON( json-events.php,  function( data ) {

alert(data.id);
alert(data.title);

});
```